# Modify array using Assembly Language

Tags: c++, assembly

I am trying to figure out how to modify the values in an array using assembly language. Here's the program:

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#include <windows.h>  

void  func(byte *p)
{ 
    __asm
    {
        lea ebx, p 
        mov[ebx],5 
    }

}
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    using byte = unsigned char;

    byte array[4];
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        array[i] = i*i;

    func(array);
    return 0;
}
```

When I step into func I can see that p points to the array. *(p+1) is 1, *(p+2) is 4, etc. I would like func to set *p to 5 but while it doesn't error out, it doesn't do that.

What I wanted to do is put the address of p into ebx and move 5 into that, but obviously I am not.

Comment: Isn't `lea` supposed to put `p`'s address into `ebx`? If so that's not what you want, you want `p`'s value there. `mov` should do that.

Comment: X86. And yes for this kind of operation, asm is definitely suboptimal. It's a beginners app for something much larger.  As for mov ebx,p : that worked!! Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`lea ebx, p` means `ebx=&p`, but you wanted `ebx=p`, which would be `mov ebx,p`